# Possible to implement canvas in Layout.xml?

Tags: android, layout, canvas

Are there any way to implement a CanvasView into the Layout file for an Activity?
My case is thta i have a class that extends View that overrides the onDraw method. And for me to add ads ontop of this Canvas i figured out i had to put them in the same Layout.

Comment: override dispatchDraw of LinearLayout instead

Comment: As i'm not very experienced with Android i need a little more indepth answer if possible.

Comment: create a class that extends LinearLayout and override that method

Comment: ok, i should instead of extending View extends LinearLayout? How would i preceed further when thinking about the adMob integration?

Comment: adMob?  sorry have no idea...